# Is it possible to swap tokens in Cardano using a SDK?

Tags: decentralized-applications, development, integration, sdk

I am looking for a SDK from any potential protocol that let me swap tokens, as you would do in Ethereum using Uniswap or SushiSwap.

Is there such a thing in Cardano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be the SundaeSwap SDK: https://github.com/SundaeSwap-finance/sundae-sdk

Comment: Yes, at the moment that is the only DEX with a SDK. Minswap team has their own private, it will be released soon.